# CentOS 6 local update repository and security updates

Tags: linux, centos, security, redhat, yum

I know that official CentOS 6 (even 7) update repositories does not provide security information. The consequence is that`yum-plugin-security` plugin and `yum check-update --security` command does not list any updates like on `RHEL` or `OEL` distros.

There is a nice script [generate_updateinfo](https://github.com/vmfarms/generate_updateinfo) which is able to inject missing piece of security information into local `yum` repository. The plugin will then work even on CentOS.

Unfortunately, I have a small issue with it. I'm not sure if the problem is with the script or with how `yum` is working.

How to reproduce the issue (tested on CentOS 6.8, x86_64, but IMO, previous/newer versions suffer from the same issue):

1. first, let's clean everything to start with clean table

> ```
> yum clean all
> ```

2. let's see what security updates are available (the system is not up-to-date)

> ```
> yum check-update --security
> ...
> 56 package(s) needed for security, out of 28 available
>
> kernel.x86_64                                 2.6.32-642.15.1.el6                         local-centos-6-x86_64-updates
> kernel-devel.x86_64                           2.6.32-642.15.1.el6                         local-centos-6-x86_64-updates
> kernel-firmware.noarch                        2.6.32-642.15.1.el6                         local-centos-6-x86_64-updates
> kernel-headers.x86_64                         2.6.32-642.15.1.el6                         local-centos-6-x86_64-updates
> libtiff.x86_64                                3.9.4-21.el6_8                              local-centos-6-x86_64-updates
> openssl.x86_64                                1.0.1e-48.el6_8.4                           local-centos-6-x86_64-updates
> sudo.x86_64                                   1.8.6p3-25.el6_8                            local-centos-6-x86_64-updates
> ```

3. now, let's install e.g. `squid` package

> ```
> yum install -y squid 
> ...
> Resolving Dependencies
> --> Running transaction check
> ---> Package squid.x86_64 7:3.1.23-16.el6_8.6 will be installed
> --> Finished Dependency Resolution
>
> Dependencies Resolved
>
> ====================================================================================================================
>  Package           Arch               Version                          Repository                              Size
> ====================================================================================================================
> Installing:
>  squid             x86_64             7:3.1.23-16.el6_8.6              lp-centos-6-x86_64-updates             1.8 M
>
> Transaction Summary
> ====================================================================================================================
> Install       1 Package(s)
>
> Total download size: 1.8 M
> Installed size: 6.3 M
> Downloading Packages:
> squid-3.1.23-16.el6_8.6.x86_64.rpm                                                           | 1.8 MB     00:00
> Running rpm_check_debug
> Running Transaction Test
> Transaction Test Succeeded
> Running Transaction
> Warning: RPMDB altered outside of yum.
>   Installing : 7:squid-3.1.23-16.el6_8.6.x86_64                                                                 1/1
>   Verifying  : 7:squid-3.1.23-16.el6_8.6.x86_64                                                                 1/1
>
> Installed:
>   squid.x86_64 7:3.1.23-16.el6_8.6
>
> Complete!
> ```

4. I would like to test update of the package so let's try to downgrade it first

> ```
> yum downgrade -y squid
> ...
> Resolving Dependencies
> --> Running transaction check
> ---> Package squid.x86_64 7:3.1.23-16.el6_8.5 will be a downgrade
> ---> Package squid.x86_64 7:3.1.23-16.el6_8.6 will be erased
> --> Finished Dependency Resolution
>
> Dependencies Resolved
>
> ====================================================================================================================
>  Package           Arch               Version                          Repository                              Size
> ====================================================================================================================
> Downgrading:
>  squid             x86_64             7:3.1.23-16.el6_8.5              lp-centos-6-x86_64-updates             1.8 M
>
> Transaction Summary
> ====================================================================================================================
> Downgrade     1 Package(s)
>
> Total download size: 1.8 M
> Downloading Packages:
> squid-3.1.23-16.el6_8.5.x86_64.rpm                                                           | 1.8 MB     00:00
> Running rpm_check_debug
> Running Transaction Test
> Transaction Test Succeeded
> Running Transaction
>   Installing : 7:squid-3.1.23-16.el6_8.5.x86_64                                                                 1/2
>   Cleanup    : 7:squid-3.1.23-16.el6_8.6.x86_64                                                                 2/2
>   Verifying  : 7:squid-3.1.23-16.el6_8.5.x86_64                                                                 1/2
>   Verifying  : 7:squid-3.1.23-16.el6_8.6.x86_64                                                                 2/2
>
> Removed:
>   squid.x86_64 7:3.1.23-16.el6_8.6
>
> Installed:
>   squid.x86_64 7:3.1.23-16.el6_8.5
>
> Complete!
> ```

5. let's rather double-check what it is installed

> ```
> rpm -qa | grep -i squid
> squid-3.1.23-16.el6_8.5.x86_64
> ```

6. at this moment, I would expect that when I check security updates again the `squid` package should be newly listed but it isn't

> ```
> yum check-update --security
> ...
> 56 package(s) needed for security, out of 28 available
>
> kernel.x86_64                                 2.6.32-642.15.1.el6                         local-centos-6-x86_64-updates
> kernel-devel.x86_64                           2.6.32-642.15.1.el6                         local-centos-6-x86_64-updates
> kernel-firmware.noarch                        2.6.32-642.15.1.el6                         local-centos-6-x86_64-updates
> kernel-headers.x86_64                         2.6.32-642.15.1.el6                         local-centos-6-x86_64-updates
> libtiff.x86_64                                3.9.4-21.el6_8                              local-centos-6-x86_64-updates
> openssl.x86_64                                1.0.1e-48.el6_8.4                           local-centos-6-x86_64-updates
> sudo.x86_64                                   1.8.6p3-25.el6_8                            local-centos-6-x86_64-updates
> ```

7. let's see what squid errata are installed on the system. This is somehow weird. From the above, I can see the squid was downgraded to `squid-3.1.23-16.el6_8.5.x86_64` (`CEBA_2016__1412 bugfix`) but `squid-3.1.23-16.el6_8.6.x86_64` (`CESA_2016__1573`) seems to be still marked as installed

> ```
> yum updateinfo list all | grep squid-3
>
> i CESA_2011__1791 Moderate/Sec.  squid-3.1.10-1.el6_2.1.x86_64
> i CEBA_2012__0122 bugfix         squid-3.1.10-1.el6_2.2.x86_64
> i CEBA_2012__0470 bugfix         squid-3.1.10-1.el6_2.3.x86_64
> i CEBA_2012__0557 bugfix         squid-3.1.10-1.el6_2.4.x86_64
> i CEBA_2012__1290 bugfix         squid-3.1.10-9.el6_3.x86_64
> i CESA_2013__0505 Moderate/Sec.  squid-3.1.10-16.el6.x86_64
> i CEBA_2013__0985 bugfix         squid-3.1.10-18.el6_4.x86_64
> i CEBA_2013__1396 bugfix         squid-3.1.10-19.el6_4.x86_64
> i CEBA_2014__0048 bugfix         squid-3.1.10-20.el6_5.x86_64
> i CESA_2014__0597 Moderate/Sec.  squid-3.1.10-20.el6_5.3.x86_64
> i CESA_2014__1148 Important/Sec. squid-3.1.10-22.el6_5.x86_64
> i CEBA_2014__1446 bugfix         squid-3.1.10-29.el6.x86_64
> i CEBA_2015__1314 bugfix         squid-3.1.23-9.el6.x86_64
> i CEBA_2016__0896 bugfix         squid-3.1.23-16.el6.x86_64
> i CESA_2016__1138 Moderate/Sec.  squid-3.1.23-16.el6_8.4.x86_64
> i CEBA_2016__1412 bugfix         squid-3.1.23-16.el6_8.5.x86_64
> i CESA_2016__1573 Moderate/Sec.  squid-3.1.23-16.el6_8.6.x86_64
> ```

8. When I try to get information for that errata there's nothing

> ```
> yum update info CESA_2016__1573
> --- NOTHING NOTHING NOTHING ---
> ```

9. When I try to list all errata but grep that one I can see it

> ```
> yum updateinfo info all | grep CESA_2016__1573 -B3 -A8
> ===============================================================================
>   Moderate CentOS squid Security Update
> ===============================================================================
>   Update ID : CESA_2016__1573
>     Release : CentOS 6
>        Type : security
>      Status : stable
>      Issued : 2016-08-04 12:51:39
> Description : Moderate CentOS squid Security Update
>    Severity : Moderate
>   Installed : true
> ```

I would like to point out that I tested this scenario (downgrade/upgrade) on RHEL6 and it works. I also tried to install old version of `squid` package directly to avoid downgrade/upgrade sequence but the result was also the same. And the issue is not related to `squid` package only. Basically, I can reproduce the issue with any package. I also tried to clean `yum` cache after package downgrade but it doesn't help.

Any idea what could be wrong?!? Why is it marked as installed when it is actually not?!? When testing on RHEL6, I can see it is not installed and then, it is included in the list of packages to be updated.

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: could this not have something to do with info in the package cache? Prehaps between downgrade and patch steps, you should clean the cache? Not that this would make the situation better, but it might be that the package manager is reading two different states.